# Why does the validateMonth method of the datejs api throw an exception and return a boolean?

Tags: datejs

Why does the validateMonth method of the datejs api throw an exception and return a boolean?

> Date.validateMonth(14)

Will throw the following error.

> Timestamp: 12/21/2012 10:56:16 AM
>      Error: RangeError: 14 is not a valid value for months.
>      Source File: http://localhost:18103/soart/scripts/date.js
>      Line: 21

To me this doesn't make sense.  It should return a boolean without throwing the exception.  The purpose of the method is to check for a valid month after all.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [DateJs documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#validateMonth) it's doing exactly what is expected. To counter this, you could wrap the check in a [try catch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp).

It might throw the exception so that it can return a meaningful error depending on what's been entered. So if a string is passed you get a different error message. In your case, the actual error message is just

```
14 is not a valid value for months
```

Comment: I caught the exception in my code and moved on.  My question is does and invalid month exception being thrown by a method checking for a valid month make sense?  It doesn't to me.  I wouldn't have batted an eye if it had thrown a NaN exception.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I think they're just trying to be helpful in the way they return errors. Not the way I would do it, `false` should be more than enough in this case!